# AJAX post JSON data arrives empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

This is my AJAX request

```
data = JSON.stringify(data);
url = base_url + "index.php/home/make_order";
//alert(url);
            
var request = $.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: data
});
request.done(function(response){
  alert('success');
});
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  alert('FAILED! ERROR: ' + errorThrown);
});
```

My problem is that when it arrives to the PHP CI-controller `$this->input->post('data')`, it is *empty*.

This is my data: as shown before the AJAX request:

```
data = {"sum":"2.250","info":[{"id":"6","name":"bla","price":"1.000"}]}
```

Comment: please show us what your `data` is ?/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First I'd like to thank all responses.
Actually it was a couple of mistakes,
**First**: as @bipen said, data must be sent as an object rather than a string. and when I tried it, it didn't work because I didn't put the **single-quote around data**

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: {'data': data}
});
```

**Second**: as @foxmulder said, **contentType** was misspelled, and should be **ContentType**
so the correct code is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  ContentType: 'application/json',
  data: {'data': data}
}).done(function(response){
  alert('success');
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  alert('FAILED! ERROR: ' + errorThrown);
});
```

and just FYI in case someone had issues with PHP fetching, this is how to do it:

```
$data = $this->input->post('data');
    $data = json_decode($data);
    $sum = $data->sum;
    $info_obj = $data->info;
    $item_qty = $info_obj[0]->quantity;
```

Comment: `contentType` Should not be capital. The reason it worked is because the capital `C` made content type an invalid jQuery property. This the request set the header to a default value i.e. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. You can verify this by removing contentType & it'll still work. You can also inspect the requests in your browser & verify this. See docs : api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 4):

send your data as object and not string.. (not sure you have done that already unless we see you data's value.. if not then try it)

```
data = JSON.stringify(data);
url = base_url + "index.php/home/make_order";
        //alert(url);

        var request = $.ajax({
            url         : url,
            type        : 'POST',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data        : {data:data} //<------here
        });
        request.done(function(response){
            alert('success');
        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('FAILED! ERROR: ' + errorThrown);
        });
```

**updated**
if as of comments you data is

```
 {"sum":"2.250","info":[{"id":"6","name":"bla","price":"1.000"}]}
```

then `data:data` is fine

```
 var request = $.ajax({
            url         : url,
            type        : 'POST',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data        : data
        });
```

bt you need to change your codeigniter codes to

```
 $this->input->post('sum') // = 2.250
 $this->input->post('info')
```

Comment: tried that too, nothing happens, i still get the $_POST global variable empty

Comment: {"sum":"2.250","info":[{"id":"6","name":"bla","price":"1.000"}]}

Comment: i tried your last suggestion, yet the POST data is still empty, it's not the variable $_POST['data'] that i'm checking in my php, i check for $_POST it's self, and it arrives empty!!! 
I'm gonna get crazy!!

Answer (score 4):

contentType should be capitalized (ContentType)

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141780/ajax-post-content-type-application-json-block-the-request)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but in which case, i believe that the post data would arrive unexpectedly rather than not arriving at all!
However, i tried it, yet no POST data =S

Comment: -1 `contentType` Should not be capital. The reason it worked is because the capital `C` made content type an invalid jQuery property. This the request set the header to a default value i.e. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. You can verify this by removing contentType & it'll still work. You can also inspect the requests in your browser & verify this. See docs : api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the **CI_Input** class to allow using json.

Place this in **application/core/MY_input.php** and you can use **$this->input->post()** as usually.

```
class MY_Input extends CI_Input {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function post($index = NULL, $xss_clean = NULL){
        if($xss_clean){
            $json = json_decode($this->security->xss_clean($this->raw_input_stream), true);
        } else {
            $json = json_decode($this->raw_input_stream, true);
        }
        if($json){
            if($index){
                return $json[$index] ?? NULL;
            }
            return $json;
        } else {
            return parent::post($index, $xss_clean);
        }
    }

}
```

If you are using **PHP5.x**. Replace

```
return $json[$index] ?? NULL;
```

with

```
return isset($json[$index]) ? $json[$index] : NULL;
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, but I think you can try with global variable `$_POST`:

```
var_dump($_POST['data']);
```

If var_dump show data, may be `$this->input...` has problem

Comment: i don't think that is the problem because `$this->input->post` this is how you get the posted data in codeigniter..

Comment: I have tried with $_POST['data'], and when i debug, the $_POST is totally empty. and as @bipen said, there is no problem with $this->input->post for CI.