# Unable to get ajax post data in PHP function

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

I have the following code in my javascript:

```
data = {};
data.token = '880a505d0a86b2sfwe434fdg43gwsf';
url = '/test/ajax/';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(error);
            },
        });
```

For the PHP, in the text controller (i.e., test.php) and ajax action, i have:

```
public function ajax()
{
       $input = $this->input->post();
       print_r($input['token']);
}
```

But i get an error saying undefined index:token. Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Please note the edit to the javascript.

```
 data = {};
val = {
"name": 'John',
"id": 10,
}
data.user = JSON.stringify(val);
        data.token = '880a505d0a86b2sfwe434fdg43gwsf';
        url = '/test/ajax/';
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(error);
                    },
                });
```

In the php, i checked to see if it is an ajax request, using `$this->input->is_ajax_request()`, and the value returned is false. Am i missing something? I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Try `data = {'token':'880a505d0a86b2sfwe434fdg43gwsf'};` instead of using `data.token` in your json string.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent: There's nothing wrong with how the OP is doing it; the suggestion above won't make any difference to the object created and data sent. The end result is identical.

Comment: I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error when i do that.

Comment: Try this `var data = "token=880a505d0a86b2sfwe434fdg43gwsf"`

Comment: @ZeeTee: That's wrong for the same reason your answer was wrong. Why post it as a comment? All it does is bypass jQuery's correct serialization code.

Comment: @user2263104: The [docs for CodeIgniter suggest](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) that the above should be working, but just for fits and giggles, you might try `$token = $this->input->post('token'); print_r($token);` to see if it works better. I can't see why it would, but I don't know CodeIgniter. (Your jQuery is fine.)

Comment: It's not wrong to pass serialized data my friend.

Comment: @ZeeTee: That particular string would be fine, but advising people to take existing correct code and replace it with code that will break as soon as they change the value on the `=` side is at best not useful, and at worst actively harmful. (You also might want to fix the `;`, but that's not the big issue.)

Comment: I get a blank page when i do $token = $this->input->post('token'); print_r($token); I'm not getting any output.I see all the data in the firebug console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ajax post json data arrives empty - codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285010/ajax-post-json-data-arrives-empty-codeigniter)

Comment: i tried data: {'data': postData}, ContentType: 'application/json' in the javascript. i still get a 500 Internal server error when i do that.

Comment: when i do console.log(data), i see all the data in the firebug console. i also looked in the Net tab of the firebug console, i see there 1 request is made after i submit, and i also see POST: myurl/test/ajax, and in the post tab in there, i see the data. i'm just unable to get all the data in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the following line of code in the config.php file in your codeigniter application folder:

Change this

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

To

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

Comment: i don't think i want to make any changes to the config. i know it should work with the same settings because i see the exact same functionality in other parts of the project that work just fine, with the same config setting.

Comment: i tried this as i couldn't find a solution, but it didn't help